# NullPointerException when adding to BigDecimal

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
String[] toppings = new String[10];
BigDecimal toppingsPrice = null;

toppings[0] = req.getParameter("extraCheese");
toppings[1] = req.getParameter("moreTomatoes");
toppings[2] = req.getParameter("extraOnions");
// ...

for(int i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
    if(toppings[i] != null) {
        toppingsPrice.add(new BigDecimal("0.99")); // <-- NPE is caused here.
        toppingsPrice = toppingsPrice.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    }
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the above code when adding `0.99` to `toppingsPrice`. I am working with money values, so I have used `BigDecimal`. Is there something wrong with how I am adding the 0.99c price?

Comment: Where are you initializing `toppingsPrice` with anything else than a `null`?

Comment: So what does the stack traceback say???? What line are you failing at, and what object can be null at that line?

Comment: What line? Include the actual error and stack trace (and if possible, indicate where in the code that line is).

Comment: In the future questions, please don't post too much noise in the code. I also suggest to try a SSCCE yourself (i.e. the smallest possible but complete working code which you can exeucte by a `main()` method). This way you can just copy'n'paste it here and it'll be clear to everyone and you'll also be able to exclude the Servlet API from being the cause of the problem.

Comment: The add method is not static, therefore it needs an instance of BigDecimal to be executed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are setting `toppingsPrice` to null and never changing it to point to something:

```
    BigDecimal toppingsPrice = null;
    ...
    toppingsPrice.add(new BigDecimal("0.99"));
```

Did you mean

```
BigDecimal toppingsPrice = new BigDecimal(0);
```

Comment: I thought `toppingsPrice.add(new BigDecimal("0.99"));` was adding to it?

Comment: @Dan: Before you can call operations on an object you must first allocate it in memory. You are adding 0.99 to a non-existent object.

Comment: Better: `BigDecimal toppingsPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize toppingsPrice

change this line

```
BigDecimal toppingsPrice = null;
```

to

```
BigDecimal toppingsPrice = new BigDecimal(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would have a look at API you would see that :

add(BigDecimal augend)

Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this + augend), and whose scale is max(this.scale(), augend.scale()).